# Aligning Floats to decimal points in Python 2.7 using the format() mini-language

Tags: python, python-2.7, format

I want to print lines so that the decimal points of the numbers align. Currently, it prints like shown below:

```
ydisp       0.176
xdisp       -0.509
```

and what I want is something like this

```
ydisp        0.176
xdisp       -0.509
```

The code that I am using is

```
print "{:{width}} {}".format(items,float_dict[items], width=12)
```

but I am a little bit lost now, I found the following section in the Python 2.7 manual under the format Mini Language

"Preceding the width field by a zero ('0') character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types. This is equivalent to a fill character of '0' with an alignment type of '='."

I cannot really get it to work with this '0' character. It would be nice if someone could give me a hint here.

Note: the dictionary keys are type string, and the values are type float.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `' '` as the sign modifier to include a space for the sign:

```
>>> '{:20} {: }'.format('ydisp', 0.176)
'ydisp                 0.176'
>>> '{:20} {: }'.format('xdisp', -0.509)
'xdisp                -0.509'
```

Note the space after the `:` colon. This causes positive numbers to be padded with a space on the left, negative numbers display a `-` instead.